# sequence duplicate table renumbering

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like give sequence numbering to duplicated recods and caluculate the time lag and  can't do it

Example :

```
id time 

A  12h30
A  13h45
A  19h48
B  8h00
B  10h12
C  22h50
D  9h02  
D  16h46
```

Expected query result

```
id time   sequence lag

A  12h30      1    0h00
A  13h45      2    1h15    
A  19h48      3    6h02
B  8h00       1    0h00
B  10h12      2    2h12
C  22h50      1    0h00
D  9h02       1    0h00
D  16h46      2    6h44
```

All I could do is to renumber a continious sequence with this query

```
SELECT count(*)as rank, a1.id


FROM  table a1, table a2  

where a1.id >=a2.id

group by a1
order by rank, a1.id
```

Any idea of th e best pratice to do it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` for the sequence and `lag()` to calculate the time difference between the previous row

```
select 
    id, 
    time,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by time) sequence,
    (case when (lag(id) over (order by id, time)) = id
         then time - (lag(time) over (order by id, time))
         else 0
    end) diff
from mytable t1
order by id, time
```

You may have to modify the case statement depending on what type the `time` column has.

Comment: Exactly ! yes time column is a timestamp an extract hour + minutes/60 it seems to does the trick, thanks